# rotating a sigmoidal curve

Tags: graphing-functions

I am using tikz to describe a load curve which is basically a [clockwise rotated sigmoidal curve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/sigmf.html?refresh=true):[load duration curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbeQi.jpg) and I need a rough curve function that comes close to it.

I remember that this is just an inverted sigmoidal curve which has a form 1/(1+exp(-a(x-c))). I thought of making x the subject but that didn't yield the curve style that I was looking for.

Comment: The inverse of the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) is the [logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) $\log x - \log(1-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your curve lacks the symmetry of the sigmoidal curve you have referenced.

You could try fitting $y=Ae^{-k_1x}+B$ to the first three hours' worth of data and $y=C-De^{k_2x}$ to the last 3.2 hours, then combining the two. This won't give a $\sinh$-like curve because $k_1 \ne k_2$.